# Simple javascript shipping calculator issue

Tags: javascript, html

so here is my code. It is a really simple shipping calculator. when I run it, all that displays is a messagebox asking the purchase price, and then it displays this " â€‹ ". Anyone know what is happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <title> Shipping Calculator</title>

<script >
var purchasePrice = window.prompt("Please enter the price of your purchase to calculate your                shipping cost.");
 var shippingPrice;

function shippingMath(purchasePrice, shippingPrice) {
     if (purchasePrice <= 25) {
        shippingPrice = 1.50;
    }
     else {
        shippingPrice = (purchasePrice * '.10');
    }
    var totalCost = (purchasePrice + shippingPrice);
    return totalCost;

}

shippingMath(purchasePrice, shippingPrice);

document.writeln("Your total is " + totalCost); 
</script>

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks. It's for a school assignment so this is kinda the only way im allowed to do it. One simple function, no arrays or anything else. Thanks!
​

Comment: My 0.02$, document.writeln is very ineffective code, use .appendChild or .innerHTML.

Answer (score 4):

Since you said this is for homework, I'm going to attempt to lead you to the answers without giving them to you outright.

A couple things you'll want to consider:

1. Is you javascript declared properly in the html
2. When is the javascript being run on the page
3. How is your function attempting to display the answer
4. Are you using the proper object (String vs Number) in your function

If you answer these 4 questions, the solution(s) should jump out at you.

Comment: well im closer. Thanks so much. I moved the writeln statement inside the function. It displays part of it but then the variable displays as some weird symbols. Probably something you were indicating in "Are you using the proper object (String vs Number) in your function"

Comment: The real problem you are having is the 3rd question: 'How is your function attempting to display the answer". document.writeln() is horribly ineffective. Read up on the use on .appendChild() or .innerHTML() suggested by @NiLL. Here is a great resource for all things [javascript](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php)

Comment: Nah, I really think the problem is #4. The others are also errors, but #4 is, I believe, key.

Answer (score 1):

One of the potential problems you may find in your code involves the scoping of your variables.

Consider the following:

```
function x() {
  var y = 10;
  return y;
}
```

The function *x* would return the value *10*, and the variable *y* would not be able to be referenced outside of the function *x*.

So the following code would show an alert box containing "10":

```
z = x();
alert(z);
```

While the following code would throw an error (or have unexpected behavior):

```
z = x();
alert(y);
```